# Adding css elements to javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Here is the piece of code which contains two CSS elements. **del** and **ins**

I want to include the whole CSS code into Javascript... But the code is one level above my experience...

Here is the CSS code:

```
del {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #b30000;
    background: #fadad7;
}
ins {
    background: #eaf2c2;
    color: #406619;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And here is the piece of code which contains those classes:

```
convertChangesToXML: function(changes) {
  var ret = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < changes.length; i++) {
    var change = changes[i];
    if (change.added) {
      ret.push("<ins class='diff'>");
    } else if (change.removed) {
      ret.push("<del class='diff'>");
    }

    ret.push(escapeHTML(change.value));

    if (change.added) {
      ret.push('</ins>');
    } else if (change.removed) {
      ret.push('</del>');
    }
  }
  return ret.join('');
},
```

How to include CSS into Javascript here?

**I don't want a separate CSS file ... Because I'm using a third party app called Storyline to create a web page and it's a lot easer to run a javascript code there without a css file**

Comment: _"I want to include the whole CSS code into Javascript"_ - Why?

Comment: The selectors are missing a `.` -> `.del { ... } .ins { ... }`

Comment: what do you mean by "include css into Javascript" exactly? I can't work out what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I've used something like : <span style='color:red'>

Comment: Just to clarify the terminology, what you seem to be talking about are elements, and the CSS rules for those elements, not classes.

Comment: I want not to use a separate CSS file ... Just this,...

Comment: "I got this code, how can I make it bad?"
"But why?" "I want this."

Comment: Guys, I know how to style using js ... The problem is how to implement it on this code...

Answer (score 0):

You can set any CSS on any DOM element using the JavaScript [style property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).

```
document.getElementById("el").style.color = "blue"
```

I suppose there are valid reasons to do this, but you may want to ask if it's efficient to set *all* of your CSS in your script files.

Comment: The problem is I can't understand ret.push("<ins class='diff'>");

Comment: How can i style something that I don't know what exactly is?

Comment: What do you mean you don't know exactly what it is? The HTML is hard coded into your page